# How can I upload a picture to a device while running appium script on AWS' device farm

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

```
String imagePath = this.getClass().getResource("/files/images.jpg").getPath();
driver.pushFile("/data/local/tmp/image.jpg", new File(imagePath));
```

This code works fine on emulators & real device but doesn't work on device farm of AWS

Comment: 1. Are you trying to do this on iOS or Android ?
2. Is the real device rooted ?

Comment: On Android & isn't rooted

Comment: how does the working code looks like? i'm facing the same issue, but also the image path could not be found on aws but works perfectly locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device farm uses physical devices and is recommend using /sdcard/ directory to pushFile. While on emulators you can use directories like /data/. This solution for work for your use case. Let us know if you see this issue again